# Are the railway tracks in the forest seen in use?

Tags: dark

One of the locations in the forest around Winden is a railway track in the forest. It runs through a slight depression and under an overpass, and must be in the vicinity of the cave entrance.

The (single-direction) track is featured repeatedly as a meeting place of the youths in 2019. At that time, the track is grown over with vegetation, as if it had been out of service for several years.

**Do we ever observe a timeframe where this track is used, or do we have to assume it was both built and decommissioned some time in between one of the 33-year intervals?**

EDIT: To be clear, it is fully possible the railway tracks are irrelevant and just serve to establish a given place. On the other hand, *Dark* is a series where small details matter and where the same places and people are shown across several time frames, so seeing something that is derelict at one point makes me wonder whether it used to have any significance at an earlier time.

Comment: Why capitalize the Title's words?

Comment: @RayButterworth: Because English has no official rules on which capitalization is correct for titles, and this one appears to be one of the [more common styles](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html).

Comment: But your 9 previous posts didn't have that style.  I wondered if there were something significant about this one.

Comment: @RayButterworth: Ooh, I see. Well, yes, another result of English lacking a fixed rule on this is that my perception of what "looks correct" changes frequently, probably influenced by what I happen to have read right before. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: FYI some people are really opposed to the "headline style" titles.  https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/when-should-we-edit-a-title/2298#2298  It's something I always go back and forth with too; but I've tried to avoid capitals for the full question title once I realized that some people find it really jarring.

Comment: @JMac: Interesting, I wasn't aware there can be "titles" that are *not* "headlines" (or vice-versa) by definition. However, I see the point that lists of SE question titles could be seen as lists of (mostly) questions, rather than headlines. Thus, I shall henceforth apply sentence-casing to my question titles iff they are a full sentence (unless I forget ...) and adapted this question's title accordingly.

Comment: Not a flat out answer, but chances are the railroad was used to build the powerplant.  They were likely in place after 1953, but not being used anymore by 1986.  They are only a significant site in 2019 as the main group of kids use the area to hang out in and the gene therapy plot point.  We are also never given a real geographic look at the area, so it's difficult to tell where things are in relation to each other.